# collapse values of same date in dataframe and create sets

Tags: python, dataframe, date, group-by, set

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKV0b.png)

I have the dataframe on top and I want to combine the values of the same date to end up with a dataframe on the bottom. Specifically, parsing the dates, if we have the same date I want to create a set of EVENT_TYPE strings and aggregate their durations for that specific day.

The goal is to create an encoding to the EVENT_TYPE occurring each specific day. I have tried groupby(), and sum(), and also to create a new dataframe and feed it with the merged rows but I fail in comparing succesfully the EVENT_TYPE so as to create the set. Could you please help me ?

Comment: If the duplicated link doesn't help, please provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: CALIFORNIA_event_type = CALIFORNIA_all_s3.groupby(['date'], as_index =True).agg({'EVENT_TYPE':''.join})
CALIFORNIA_duration = CALIFORNIA_all_s3.groupby(['date'], as_index =True).agg({'DURATION':'sum'})

Comment: I solved it with this